# Как посмотреть через терминал, в каких проектах нужно делать коммиты и пушить в репозиторий?

Tags: ubuntu, git, bash, github, консоль

Бывает такое, что на работе за день приходится выполнять какие-то задачи в несколько проектах. А также я храню настройки для системы базу знаний на bitbucket. И когда много репозиторий на машине, легко можно забыть что-то запушить.

Я работаю в убунту и хотелось бы через терминал в конце рабочего дня запустить команду, которая бы проверила все проекты, если не остались среди них незапушенные.

К сожалению я не силен в баш скриптах.
Может у кого уже имеется готовый скрипт.
Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: Ну так просто же можно написать скриптик, который пройдется по всем репам и выполнит `git diff` или `git status`. Нужно глянуть, что при этом вернет `echo $?`.

Comment: Типа того `if [[ -z $(git diff) ]]`. Если изменений нет, то это вернет истину, а это наоборот  `if [[ -n $(git diff) ]]`

Answer (score 4):

что-нибудь вроде такого:

```
$ find ~ -type d -name .git | while read p; do (cd "$p"/..; git status --porcelain --branch | grep -q ahead && dirname "$p"); done
```

команда ищет в вашем домашнем каталоге репозитории, т.е. каталоги с именем `.git`, для каждого из найденных:

1. делает текущим каталог на один уровень выше (там обычно и располагается «work tree» — рабочий каталог)
2. проверяет наличие строки `ahead` в выводе `git status --porcelain --branch`
3. при её наличии выдаёт имя каталога в *stdout*

---

по поводу опций команды `status`.

пример вывода (если имеется неотправленный в общее хранилище коммит):

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

эту информацию можно получить в более удобном для обработки виде:

```
$ git status --porcelain --branch 
## master...origin/master [ahead 1]
```

вот наличие строки `ahead` как раз и стоит проверять.

---

доп. чтение: `$ man git-status`

---

обновление. каюсь, проглядел эти слова в заголовке: «в каких проектах нужно делать коммиты» и сосредоточился только на тексте вопроса, где речь только про невыполненную команду `push`.

проверить, нет ли модифицированных файлов, можно практически той же командой, только заменить

```
git status --porcelain --branch | grep -q ahead
```

на

```
git status --porcelain | grep -q .
```

Answer (score 0):

на мой взгляд можно просто поставить тему, например
[powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k)

или любую другую с поддержкой git и не писать лишние команды

Comment: а если так хочется пройтись по папкам, то к конце рабочего дня просто запускаете алиас или скрипт, что Вам больше нравится, типо cd work_folder1 && cd work_folder2 && cd work_folder3 и .т.д. - сразу станет видно статус репозитория.

Comment: *на мой взгляд можно просто поставить тему* — «как бы мне не забыть ласты взять на летний отдых? да просто надень ласты, панамку, рюкзак и шубу, и не снимай до лета».

Comment: ахахаха))) Вы имеете ввиду что это "утяжелит" терминал?

Comment: нет, что вы. вся отображаемая (по вашему предложению) информация собирается без участия оборудования. божьим промыслом, вестимо.

Comment: не знаю в чем претензия)) ну порождает эта тема пару дополнительных процессов, но это не настолько сильно что бы было заметно или как то сказалось на производительности, даже на моём стареньком компе.